# filter out repeated rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, filtering

**|product|**

| date | item |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-15 | nike |
| 2021-01-15 | nike |
| 2021-01-15 | adidas |
| 2021-02-20 | nike |
| 2021-02-20 | nike |
| 2021-02-20 | adidas |

I want to get next result:

| date | item |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-15 | nike |
| 2021-01-15 | adidas |
| 2021-02-20 | nike |
| 2021-02-20 | adidas |

```
select * from (select distinct date from product) my_dates
               join product on my_dates.date = product.date
```

nothing is filtered out!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct date, item
from t;
```